# How can I transform a coordinate system into the origin coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I have two cameras, camera 1 which is also the origin coordinate system and camera 2. I also have a rigid Object which contains 88 points that the camera 1 detected.

I now have another coordinate system, let's call it coordinate system X which is somewhere located at the vector T. The vector T is the baseline which connects the optical center of camera 1 and camera 2, a.k.a the Translation of camera 2 relative to camera 1. The vector T  and also the rotation of camera 2 relative to the origin coordinate system is given

The location of coordinate system is unknown. I also have the same object displayed in coordinate system x.

I now want to align the coordinate system X into the origin coordinate system such that the orientation of the  object is displayed in both coordinate systems the same way. That means I want to determine the transformation matrix which consists of the rotation and translation align coordinate system x into origin coordinate system

How do I approach this task ?

In the following are a sketch of the camera orientation and the object displayed in the origin coordinate system and the coordinate system x.

[camera orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNYmu.png)

[object displayed in origin coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4aRN.png)

[object displayed in coordinate system x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oSqd.png)

Comment: I tried to tackle this task by assuming that the x axis of coordinate system x is also aligned to the vector T and used the directive cosine to calculate the angle between x axis coordinate system x and x axis origin coordinate system. But I figured out by doing this that the coordinate system x is further rotated such that the x axis is not directed in the same way as vector T

Comment: Look up “epipolar geometry.”

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the concept of Epipolar geometry, but I do not understand how this will help my problem.

Comment: The Epipolar geometry is used to find the rotation and translation from the coordinate system from camera 2 in relation to camera 1. But my unknown coordinate system is located somewhere on the translation vector of camera 2 relative to camera 1. The translation and rotation matrix for camera 2 is already known